# Control the rate of data transferred through nodejs request module

Tags: node.js, download

I am trying to achieve the following: build a module that allows downloading multiple file in segments but also allows controlling the bandwidth/data rate.

I am triggering multiple request instance for one file and passing "Range" within the headers to download segments but is this the right way to achieve so via nodejs?

Most of my search through the week points to throttle in regards to my second issue, but I read/think this is controlling the rate at which data is written but not the rate at which data is downloaded.

So in short, is it possible to i.e

```
request(url).on('data', function(chunk){
    // control the rate at which data is triggered/size of chunk downloaded per second
});
```

I have also reviewed the raw http module from nodejs, but can't find any hint around what am trying to achieve.

I was rather working forward an option such as

```
request({
    url: url,
    rate: myRate // i.e 5000 kbps,
}).on('data', function(chunk){
    // process chunk here
    // chunk will never be above 5000 kbps and triggers chunks of 5000 per second
})
```

**EDIT**

Thinking over on my last example, I assume being able to define the rate this way would represent a lot of limitation in terms of i.e if I want to increase/decrease the download rate during the request (while data is being downloaded, or pause and change the rate and then resume). But hoping somehow this explains what I am aiming to achieve.

Not expecting a working solution but any hints towards where I should be looking into would be appreciated.